# Add CORS Headers to a Lambda Function - serverless nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cors, http-headers, serverless

it's my first time working with AWS & Serverless framework and I'm struggling really hard with the

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource"

error, in an App that uses AWS services and serverless framework.

In my serverless.yml file, I added this lines to the handler function:

```
 - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /{proxy+}
          cors:
            origin: "*"
            headers: "*"
```

According to what I've found on Google, the next step is properly add the headers in the function itself.

My handler function is like this

```
const routes = require("./routes");
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(routes);

exports.handler = (event, context) =>
  awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
```

And the functions that are routed into it, like the login function for example, are like this:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const params = {
      AuthFlow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
      UserPoolId: userPoolId,
      ClientId: clientId,
      AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: email,
        PASSWORD: password,
      },
    };
    const userIsValidated = await cognito.adminInitiateAuth(params).promise();
    res.send({
      message: "Success",
      token: userIsValidated.AuthenticationResult.IdToken,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    const message = error.message ? error.message : "Internal server error";
    res.send({ message });
  }
};
```

Concluding, I am stuck in where to add the headers and how:

- If I add them in the handler function, I'm not managing how not to break it.
- If I add them in the functions that route to it, I'm not managing how to call them from another function with the headers.

Thanks!